# what is the difference between using the request.session.flush() and simply using del request.session['key'] to log out the user in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have used the following:

```
 def LogOut(request):
   request.session.flush()

 def LogOut(request):
   try:
      del request.session['member_id']
   except KeyError:
      pass
```

I looked up the database file and noticed that the former did remove the session data from
the table, the latter, however, did not.
I can't wrap my head around the difference between the two. Why doesn't the second remove the session data even though i'd assigned the member's id to the aformentioned key while creating the session.

Comment: del is a Python construct, it doesn’t have anything to do with the database. Deleting data from RAM doesn’t change the fact it’s stored in a database.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is,

1. `request.session.flush()` is delete all session values on that request. while `del request.session['member_id']` only delete session value with key `member_id`.
2. As you can see, `request.session.flush()` also remove the data from the database, while the `del request.session['member_id']` doesn't. The `request.session.flush()` delete the record from `django_session` table. But, `del request.session['member_id']` only delete session data with key `member_id` on the particular session record.

   You can take a look at the `session_data` on the `django_session` table. It's base64 value, you can decode that value, and see what's the real value. You'll see that `member_id` doesn't exist on that `session_data`, but the session record still exist.

```
Why doesn't the second remove the session data?
```

Because the second just manipulate the python list variable, while the first one is perform sql delete query on the table. If you need to understand `request.session.flush()`, you need to take a look at the core source code. You'll find it does perform sql delete query on the table.

Comment: Then what exactly does the second one remove?  I know its a key-value pair, but what does the key-value pair signify?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the second doesn't delete the session record from the DB, but it does delete that key from session data on the particular session record.

Comment: I think you need to take a look on how session works, especially in Django. Session is loaded from the DB (since you're using DB as session backend) on the beginning, then session is store (update) it back to the DB on the end of the request. When you delete that key, then when the session is getting update, it doesn't include that key, since it's getting deleted.

Comment: What does the session key usually hold

Comment: Let make it clear, you can check one of the record of session_data from `django_session` DB. It just base64 value. You can decode that base64 value, then you can see what's the real value.

Comment: @Moaz_ Do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

In database backed session, cookie contains session id, not the data, and the same session id along with session objects are stored in database.
When you delete a session object, only that session object(refer session_data column in django_session table) from the table will be removed and not the entry from the table. you can see that entry still exists.

When you call flush(), the cookie containing sessionid and the entry in the database will be removed. Hence, the same session will not be used again.